# How to apply theme-specific styles in Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm creating a Windows Phone (7.5) app where I have the need to change some styles based on which Theme (Dark or Light) is selected.

It's not good enough for this app just to try and find a color which works in both cases.

Some of this can be done in code I know, but I would like to put it in xaml, as this is really just markup/styling which I don't want in my C# code :)

Here's what I would like to do in pseudo code:

```
    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundImageBrush" ApplyForTheme="Dark" Stretch="None" 
ImageSource="/WindowsFanDkApp;component/Content/AppBackground.jpg"/>

    <ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundImageBrush" ApplyForTheme="Light" Stretch="None" 
ImageSource="/WindowsFanDkApp;component/Content/AnotherAppBackground.jpg"/>
```

Can't seem to find any resources about how to do this...so I'm afraid it's not possible :(

Answer (score 0):

You can search in the Application's Resource for a specific key and then change the uri of the imagebrush.

Here is the tip :

```
var isLightTheme = (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];
var theBrush = new ImageBrush();
var imageUri = new Uri(isLightTheme == Visibility.Visible ? "bg-light.jpg" : "bg-dark.jpg", UriKind.Relative);
theBrush .ImageSource = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage(imageUri);
```

**EDIT** :
How to load style at startup

```
public App()
{
   ...
    //dynamic load style
    LoadDictionary(); 
   ...     
}

private void LoadDictionary()
{
    var dictionaries = Resources.MergedDictionaries;
    dictionaries.Clear();
    string source = String.Format("/MyProject;component/DarkStyles.xaml");
    var themeStyles = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative) };
    dictionaries.Add(themeStyles);
}
```

Comment: And then how do you apply the "theBrush" to the resources so it's used in the entire app?

Comment: 'theBrush' is just an example. The first line of code is important. You can load styles at startup using ResourceDictionary / MergedDictionaries. See edit

Comment: It does not properly work, for instance I created theme for textblock (set FontSize and Foreground). When I has applied theme, I saw that foreground does not change but FontSize applied. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As Cybermaxs suggested, you can use ResourceDictionary / MergedDictionaries. Here is how to do that with XAML:

```
<Application.Resources>
  <ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
      <ResourceDictionary Source="TestStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
  </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```